# Nav Component implicit deeplink not working with res string

Tags: android, android-studio, deep-linking

When i add a deeplink like so 
`<deepLink
 android:id="@+id/deepLinkParentShortId"
 app:uri="@string/deep_link_parent_short_id" />`

The uri is ignored, if i hard code it in place it works fine. Debugging and checking the actual deeplink on the Node revealed the uri looks the same in both cases.

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, the navigation library hasn't supported this yet. You must specify the uri as a pure string or find some other way around.

One other way is handling the deep link intent inside your host activity and let that actitiy take care of navigating to the target destination.